# OkHttp: SSLPeerUnverifiedException Failed to find a trusted cert that signed X.509 Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

Actually, this week, I have the same question as the following

> [OkHttpClient and Certificate Authority Validation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772360/okhttpclient-and-certificate-authority-validation-in-android)

In my phone (Motorola, Android 4.1.2), I disable all DigiCert CAs (inside `Settings - Security - Trusted credentials - System`).

My code below:

```
public class CertPinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cert_pin);

        try {
            CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add("github.com", "sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=")
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())
                    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS")
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.e("onFailure","-------------------------------------------------");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    Log.d("onResponse", response.body().string());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
            throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.github); // this is exported from Chrome then stored inside \app\src\main\res\raw path
        Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        caInput.close();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
}
```

My app got the following logcat (sorry I truncate because it's too long)

```
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 E/onFailure: -------------------------------------------------
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Failed to find a trusted cert that signed X.509 Certificate:
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err: [
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err: [
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:   Version: V3
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:   Subject: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:   Signature Algorithm: SHA256WithRSAEncryption, params unparsed, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
06-14 09:10:10.065 30176-30211/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:   Key: 
...................................................................................
06-14 09:17:56.813 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.tls.CertificateChainCleaner$BasicCertificateChainCleaner.clean(CertificateChainCleaner.java:132)
06-14 09:17:56.813 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.CertificatePinner.check(CertificatePinner.java:149)
06-14 09:17:56.813 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:252)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:196)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:171)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:111)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:187)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-14 09:17:56.823 5934-5984/com.example.okhttps3 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

However, `onResponse` called in the following cases:

1. Both `.sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())` and `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` removed;
2. Only `.sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())` removed; (actually, with emulator, when system CA disabled, `onFailure` called and inside it `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found` thrown)
3. Only `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` removed.

Logcat with `onResponse` as below (too long so I truncate):

```
06-14 09:06:23.143 26571-26616/com.example.okhttps3 D/onResponse: <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                                  <html lang="en" class="">
                                                                  .....
```

So, my questions are:

1. The same as the link at the beginning in my question (actually his 1st issue);
2. Why does my app get `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Failed to find a trusted cert that signed X.509 Certificate` when `certificatePinner` used with `getSSLSocketFactory`? Please note that the inner message of this `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` is different from `Certificate pinning failure!` as mentioned in [this JavaDoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html).

---

**UPDATE:**

*For 1st issue:*

Looks like this issue (System/User Trusted credentials not effective) only happened in my phones which run Android 4.1.2, I have checked 02 devices, so I think I should contact the manufacturer.

*For 2nd issue:*

From the comment of @Robert below `"I assume you have to include the full certificate chain (or the root certificate if the server sends you the chain), not only the leave certificate"`, I have exported Root CA instead, as the following screenshot, although not completed chain, and inside `getSSLSocketFactory` I changed to `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.github_rootca);`

**Now, my 2nd issue is solved!**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your first "question".

Comment: @Robert: it looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772360/okhttpclient-and-certificate-authority-validation-in-android), actually his 1st issue. Because I disabled system CAs, however although `.sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())` removed, `onResponse` still called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificate pinning is an additional security, therefore the certificate must be trusted by the used TrustManager **and** it have to match the pinned certificate.

As you have disable the DigiCert CA certificates the certificate is not trusted by the sued TrustManager and therefore you are getting the SSLPeerUnverifiedException.

The behavior as I described is documented in the JavaDoc of [CertificatePinner](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CertificatePinner.html):

> Note about self-signed certificates
>
> CertificatePinner can not be used to pin self-signed certificate if such certificate is not accepted by TrustManager.

Comment: As in my question, if only `.sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())` removed, `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` not got

Comment: I think the cert that github uses it not self-signed

Comment: The exception message in documention link is `SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate pinning failure!`, however, my app got `SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Failed to find a trusted cert that signed X.509 Certificate`

Comment: @BNK: In this case self-signed just means "not accepted by the used Trustmanager". You just have to interpret the sentence and derive the consequences from it.

Comment: @BNK: As I said your used TrustManager does not work as expected. I have not tested it but I assume you have to include the full certificate chain (or the root certificate if the server sends you the chain), not only the leave certificate.

Comment: If only `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` used, so that means no TrustManager here, am I right? Then, in my phone `onResponse` called, in emulator (with the same API 16), `onFailure` called with `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

Comment: @BNK: Please read what I have read and what I have quoted. Using only `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` means the default trust manager is used. Because otherwise you cloud use it for self-signed certificates.

Comment: Thanks for your info, however, if so, I think `onFailure` should be called when system CA disabled (as in the emulator)?

Comment: Hi Robert, please read my updated answer about 1st issue, since your comment has helped me to solved my 2nd issue, so please update your answer and I will tick it as accepted one, many thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you disable your default system certificate trustore, (using or not the Certificate pinning without a custom trustore) you will always get an exception because will not be possible to verify the peer certificate, so

- If you dont use `Certificate pinning` and your `default system certificate trustore` is `working` (with the Digicert High Assurance EV Root CA) your connection will be **OK**
- If you dont use `Certificate pinning` and your `default system certificate trustore` is `not working` your connection will **FAIL**
- If you use Certificate pinning and your default system certificate trustore is working (with the Digicert High Assurance EV Root CA) your connection will be **OK**
- If you use `Certificate pinning` and your `default system certificate trustore` is `not working` your connection will **FAIL**
- If you use `Certificate pinning` and your `default system certificate trustore` is `not working` and you setup a `custom trustore with the digicert CA` your connection will be **OK**
- If you use `Certificate pinning` and your `default system certificate trustore is not working` and you `setup a custom trustore without the digicert CA` your connection will **FAIL**

An example (Java) using Certificate pinning + sslSocketFactory + custom trustmanager (based on [OkHttp3 CustomTrust example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java))

(digicert.cer contains the the Digicert High Assurance EV Root CA)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.CertificatePinner;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class OkHttpTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add("github.com", "sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=").build();

            X509TrustManager trustManager;
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

            try {
                trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/digicert.cer")));
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
                sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner).build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS").build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("onResponse: " + response.body().string());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private X509TrustManager trustManagerForCertificates(InputStream in) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(in);
        if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
        }

        // Put the certificates a key store.
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray(); // Any password will work.
        KeyStore keyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
        int index = 0;
        for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
            String certificateAlias = Integer.toString(index++);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
        }

        // Use it to build an X509 trust manager.
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, password);
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }
        return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    }

    private KeyStore newEmptyKeyStore(char[] password) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            InputStream in = null;
            keyStore.load(in, password);
            return keyStore;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with my code, if I remove both `.sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())` and `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)`, in my phone, `onResponse` still called, in emulator, `onFailure` called

Comment: @vzamanillo : He is right. The connection is made on my phone even when the particular certificate is disabled in android system's trusted CAs.

Comment: @Ashwin and vzamanillo, please read my updated answer about 1st issue, thanks

Comment: @BNK : Thanks for the update.It happens on my phone too which runs Marshmallow (6.0) Motog3. This looks like a serious issue either on the manufactoruers side or operating system side or the OkHttpClient side. We must report this!

Comment: Working solution. Thanks.